# preceding-sibling [1] is not last

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to thank's to this community for helping me so much lately. You are my saviours :)

I'm trying to verify when a number (x) is different from the previous one
So my list was sorted, first I have:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="house">
    <xsl:sort select="./point/x"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

the important part is:

```
<xsl:template match="house">

    <xsl:if test="./point/x != preceding-sibling::house[1]/point/x">
        <br/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::house[1]/point/x"/>
             value changed to <xsl:value-of select="./point/x"/>        
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Just printing -->
    <br/>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./point/x"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./point/y"/></td>

</xsl:template>
```

Note I have 2 values in print, x and y, but Im only working with x
I want output to be something like:
xy
00
01
0 value change to 1

10
11

somehow my result goes get the wrong previous number

00
1 value change to 0
01
0 value change to 1
10
0 value change to 1
11

Progress:
I found out that by removing the sort the output is correct

00
0 value change to 1
10
1 value change to 0
01
0 value change to 1
11

So my question now is... how can I do this procedure?

Comment: Can you post some sample XML?

Comment: `preceding-sibling` *always* refers to document order, never to the order of your `<xsl:sort>`. There's nothing messed up, it just does not do what you expect.

Comment: You may be interested in a simpler and much more efficient solution(s) than the currently accepted one -- both in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Tomalak is being modest. His answer isn't bad and he writes good XSLT code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a much more efficient (linear vs O(N^2*log(N)) XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kHouseById" match="house" use="generate-id()"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vIdsOfSorted">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/house">
    <xsl:sort select="point/x" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat(generate-id(), ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>


 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="traverseIds">
   <xsl:with-param name="pIds" select="concat($vIdsOfSorted, ' ')"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="count(house)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="traverseIds">
   <xsl:param name="pIds"/>
   <xsl:param name="pLength"/>
   <xsl:param name="pPos" select="1"/>
   <xsl:param name="pPrevId" select="''"/>

   <xsl:if test="not($pPos > $pLength)">
     <xsl:variable name="vId" select="substring-before($pIds, ' ')"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vHouse" select="key('kHouseById', $vId)"/>

     <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat('&#xA;(', $vHouse/point/x, ',', $vHouse/point/y, ')')"/>
       <xsl:if test="not($pPos >= $pLength)">
        <xsl:variable name="vNextId" select=
         "substring-before(substring-after($pIds, ' '), ' ')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vNextHouse" select="key('kHouseById', $vNextId)"/>

        <xsl:if test="not($vHouse/point/x = $vNextHouse/point/x)">
         <xsl:value-of select=
           "concat('&#xA;value changed to ', $vNextHouse/point/x)"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:call-template name="traverseIds">
          <xsl:with-param name="pIds" select="substring-after($pIds, ' ')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="$pLength"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pPos" select="$pPos+1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pPrevId" select="$vId"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
  <house>
    <point>
      <x>1</x><y>0</y>
    </point>
  </house>
  <house>
    <point>
      <x>0</x><y>1</y>
    </point>
  </house>
  <house>
    <point>
      <x>0</x><y>0</y>
    </point>
  </house>
  <house>
    <point>
      <x>1</x><y>1</y>
    </point>
  </house>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
(0,1)
(0,0)
value changed to 1
(1,0)
(1,1)
```

**In case you don't love recursion, here is a non-recursive XSLT 1.0 solution that uses the `xxx:node-set()` extension function**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vrtfSorted">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/house">
            <xsl:sort select="point/x" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSorted" select="ext:node-set($vrtfSorted)/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="$vSorted">
            <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:if test=
              "$vPos > 1 
             and 
               not(point/x = $vSorted[position()=$vPos -1]/point/x)">
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('value changed to ', point/x)"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',point/x,',',point/y, ')')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces exactly the same, correct result**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vSorted">
   <xsl:perform-sort select="house">
     <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(point/x)"/>
   </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "(for $n   in 2 to count($vSorted/*),
        $n-1 in $n -1,
        $vNewX in $vSorted/*[$n]/point/x,
        $vOldX in $vSorted/*[$n-1]/point/x,
        $vNewY in $vSorted/*[$n]/point/y,
        $vOldY in $vSorted/*[$n-1]/point/y,
        $remark in
              if($vNewX ne $vOldX)
                then concat('&#xA;value changed to ', $vNewX, '&#xA;')
                else '&#xA;'
     return
       concat('(',$vOldX,',',$vOldY, ')', $remark)
     ),
     concat('(',$vSorted/*[last()]/point/x,',',
                $vSorted/*[last()]/point/y, ')'
            )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
 (0,1)
 (0,0)
value changed to 1
 (1,0)
 (1,1)
```

Comment: once again I want to thank you for your help. I'm still trying to understand everything.

Comment: @NavySeal: You are welcome. Please, ask any questions - I'd be glad to explain.

Answer (score 3):

Not very nice, but if you must know *"the previous value of x according to a certain order"*, then you must order the nodes again and fetch the right one:

```
<xsl:template match="house">
    <xsl:variable name="current-position" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="preceding-x-ordered">
      <xsl:for-each select="../house">
        <xsl:sort select="point/x" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = $current-position - 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="point/x" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1 and point/x != $preceding-x-ordered">
        <br/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$preceding-x-ordered"/>
        <xsl:text> value changed to </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="point/x"/>        
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Just printing -->
    <br/>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="point/x"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="point/y"/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT is supposed to be side-effects free, which means that the processor can process templates in any order it wishes without changing the overall result. Not "knowing" what it did in the last iteration of a loop is a consequence of that requirement. Hence there is no way that the `preceding-sibling` axis can know what node was processed earlier.

Comment: i guess I am supose to prevent this by using restrictions on schema?

Comment: If you can enforce sorted XML via schema, you could do that. `preceding-sibling` would start to work the way you want to.

Comment: This is O(N^2) solution. This can be done with an algorithm with linear complexity.

Comment: Actually, the time complexity of this solution is worse than quadratical -- it is O(N^2*log(N)).

Comment: @Dimitre You are right, it's catastropic. I could not think of a better solution that did not require the `node-set()` extension. Is there one?

Comment: @Tomalak: Why aren't you sleeping?

Comment: @Dimitre Good question. Age-related insomnia, I'd say. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Clever solution! I already gave my +1 to you earlier. (You should have kept the `node-set()` based approach for reference)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate approach. You might want to think in terms of groups. As you have tagged the question xslt 2.0, this does come with some useful grouping functions (In xslt 1.0 you would have to make use of the Meunchian Grouping technique)

Effectively you are grouping houses by the **point/x** value, so you get each distinct group like so:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="house" group-by="point/x">
   <xsl:sort select="point/x"/>
```

Then you could iterate over the houses within the group like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="point/y"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="houses">
      <xsl:text>xy&#13;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="house" group-by="point/x">
         <xsl:sort select="point/x"/>
         <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' value changed to ', point/x, '&#13;')" />
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sort select="point/y"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(point/x, point/y, '&#13;')" />
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="point/x" />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML....

```
<houses>
    <house><point><x>1</x><y>0</y></point></house>
    <house><point><x>2</x><y>1</y></point></house>
    <house><point><x>0</x><y>1</y></point></house>
    <house><point><x>1</x><y>1</y></point></house>
    <house><point><x>0</x><y>0</y></point></house>
    <house><point><x>2</x><y>0</y></point></house>
</houses>
```

The following is output:

```
xy
00
01
0 value changed to 1
10
11
1 value changed to 2
20
21
```